# Standard selection, cut, copy paste not working with SearchView in action bar

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, searchview

I am using SearchView in action bar in my android application. I am using support v-7 library.

I find standard text selection, cut, copy and paste not working in the search text field. It works by default in normal EditText objects.

Please let me know the way to get standard text selection, text cut, copy paste working or SearchView.

Regards,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
First get a reference to the searchView

`int searchTextViewId = mSearchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
mSearchTextView = (TextView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchTextViewId);`

Now set `android:textIsSelectable` property to true;
`mSearchTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true)`